# Cookie expire date in the past in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, http-headers

I'm writing/updating a cookie, however every time I do this and I look at the chrome dev tools, it tells me the cookie expires 30 minutes ago, not 30 minutes from now.

```
HttpCookie cookie;

if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(name))
{
  cookie = Request.Cookies[name];
}
else
{
  cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
}

cookie.Value = value;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
Response.Cookies.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: `cookie expires 30 minutes ago` , expires or expired?

Comment: That is the odd thing, it is still writing it to the browser, but the expires/Max-age is set to 30 minutes in the past.  Stepping through the code sets it correctly 30 minutes from now.

Answer (score 1):

What time zone are you in? If for instance you're in UTC - 1 then:

- Current local time is 12:00
- UTC time is 13:00
- cookie expires 12:30 (since you're not using UtcNow)
- Browser may think 12:30 is UTC time and thus is the past.

This is kinda-sorta plausible, so take it with a large pinch of salt!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(name))
{
  response.Cookies.Remove(name);
}

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
cookie.Value = value;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

**OR**

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(name) && Request.Cookies[name]!=null)
{
  var cookie = Request.Cookies[name];
  cookie.Value = value;
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
  Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);//To update a cookie, you need only to set the cookie again using the new values and also you must include all of the data you want to retain.
}
else
{
  var cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
  cookie.Value = value;
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```